# laravel print preview using laravel-dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I am using Laravel 5.4 and using

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.0",
```

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

i have follwoing code in controller

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('print.print', $data);
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

As it will download pdf  properly but i am looking to preview the content in the view to print.
i have googled lot still not able to get it

Comment: You can do a workaround for printing using JavaScript,

Comment: is it possble to view pdf in new browser tab without downlaoding

Comment: You can just use the `->stream()` method?

Comment: i ahve tried stream but its downlaoding not view

Comment: You need to send the pdf to the new window then execute `window.print()` the browser will preview the pdf as print

Answer (score 3):

You can use `stream()` function as stated in documentation [here](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage).

According to documentation of `dompdf`, 
When you use stream like this:

```
$dompdf->stream('filename.pdf');
```

In default, you will see a `download dialouge box`.

But, you can add parameter `Attachment` value to `false` so that you can view `pdf` in browser.

Here is what you need to do:

```
$dompdf->stream("filename.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
```

This might help you.

Comment: using stream with array nothing happen its download that file.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this and manage to make it work with the following snippet:

```
$html = view('desktop.bill', $data)->render();
return @\PDF::loadHTML($html, 'utf-8')->stream(); // to debug + add the follosing headers in controller ( TOP LEVEL )
```

Besides the upper command, you will need to add on a TOP LEVEL, like first lines in the controller, the following hearders:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="document.pdf"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```